# What's the meaning of "++" after a union in C?

Tags: c, union, symbols

Here's the code

```
int AreSymEquivalent_hkl(const T_SgInfo *SgInfo, int h1, int k1, int l1,
                                                 int h2, int k2, int l2)
{
  int     iList, mh2, mk2, ml2, hm, km, lm;
  T_RTMx  *lsmx;


  mh2 = -h2;
  mk2 = -k2;
  ml2 = -l2;

  /* check list of symmetry operations */

  lsmx = SgInfo->ListSeitzMx;

  for (iList = 0; iList < SgInfo->nList; iList++, lsmx++)
  {
    hm = lsmx->s.R[0] * h1 + lsmx->s.R[3] * k1 + lsmx->s.R[6] * l1;
    km = lsmx->s.R[1] * h1 + lsmx->s.R[4] * k1 + lsmx->s.R[7] * l1;
    lm = lsmx->s.R[2] * h1 + lsmx->s.R[5] * k1 + lsmx->s.R[8] * l1;

    if      ( h2 == hm &&  k2 == km &&  l2 == lm)
      return  (iList + 1);

    else if (mh2 == hm && mk2 == km && ml2 == lm)
      return -(iList + 1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It's a function defined from a quite famous package 'sginfo' in the area of computational crystallography. 
(You can download from here if you want: https://github.com/rwgk/sginfo/tree/master/sginfo_1_01)
So i'm sure there's no bug in it. The question is in the lines

```
  lsmx = SgInfo->ListSeitzMx;

  for (iList = 0; iList < SgInfo->nList; iList++, lsmx++)
```

Where "SgInfo" is a big struct I did not put it here, containing "ListSeitzMx" -- an attribute of a union named "T_RTMx" which consists some matrices information. The definition is as follows:

```
typedef union
  {
    struct { int R[9], T[3]; } s;
    int                        a[12];
  }
  T_RTMx;
```

That's the part confuses me, "++" after a union. What I know is that the value of int before "++" adds to 1, but the union type makes no sense. Or I have made a big mistake of the whole thing? That "lsmx" is not a union or something...
As a beginner of C, I have tried to write a small test script on this question but the bugs made me crazy. So I finally decided to publish this question...

Comment: `x++` is equivalent to `(t=x, x=x+1, t)`.  If you aren't using the expression value, then it's equivalent to `x=x+1`.

Comment: `lsmx` isn't a `T_RTMx`; it's a `T_RTMx*` (a pointer)

Comment: `lsmx` is a pointer. Doing `lsmx++` gives the next element of the pointer. Presumably, this pointer is pointing to an array of structs and `lsmx++` gives the next element in this array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually not adding to the union. You are adding to the address.

Consider a similar situation:

```
struct abc {
    int a, b, c;
    //Lots more nonsense
};
```

Now,

```
struct abc z;
struct abc *a;
a = &z
```

This tells that `a` stores address of `struct abc` type.

Now let's revise how pointers work.

Let's suppose `z` resides at a location `1000`.
`a` stored that value. When I do `*a`, I refer to memory location `1000` upto `sizeof(struct abc)`. As `a` is a pointer to the type `struct abc`, you can do:

```
a->c = 2;
```

or something like that.

When you say:

```
int *b;
```

It practically can store address of any other type. If you really like to be adventurous, you can do this:

```
b = &z;
```

You may or may not receive warnings depending on your compiler.

When I store `&z`, the only thing the compiler does is treat the value at the address of `z` as an `int`. So `b` has the value `1000`.

Now when you do `*b`, you refer to the address `1000` upto `sizeof(int)`.

Concluding this,

```
b++;
```

This would just do `1000 + sizeof(int)`, and reach to next `int`.

```
a++;
```

would do `1000 + sizeof(struct abc)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
lsmx++
```

is equivalent to

```
( orig = lsmx, lsmx = lsmx + 1, orig )
```

In other words,

- `lsmx++` adds one to `lsmx` (as if you had done (`lsmx = lsmx + 1`).
- `lsmx++` evaluates to the original value of `lsmx`, but that is discarded in your code.

`lsmx` is a pointer. Adding `1` to a pointer increases the address by the size of the pointed thing (`sizeof(*lsmx)`).

For example,

```
T_RTMx foo[5] = ...;
T_RTMx *lsmx = foo;   # Same as &( foo[0] )   # Points to foo[0]
lsmx++;                                       # Points to foo[1]
lsmx += 2;                                    # Points to foo[3]
```

Keep in mind that `a[b]` is completely equivalent to `*(a+b)`.